# How can I edit google-service.json where in root folder from app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to create a Firebase Cloud Messaging client. I want to get id, project id, package name and etc. from user and edit my google-service.json file. From textviews users can change informations and can use with their projects informations. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: So, you are trying to "sign in" to multiple Firebase cloud messaging servers? It's not a chat room - I don't it works like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desire to create a user configurable client is unusual.  You must have some very special requirements.  I don't think the type of FCM client configuration you want to do is possible.  I'll explain my reasoning.

First, the `google-services.json` file is processed at *build* time, not *run* time. It is parsed by the [Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin), which generates an XML file of string resources at `.../app/build/generated/res/google-services/{buildType}/values/values.xml`.

When an app that uses Firebase starts up, the [FirebaseInitProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/provider/FirebaseInitProvider) configures itself using those string resources, and creates the default instance of [FirebaseApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp). The default `FirebaseApp` is used by [FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging).

Some Firebase APIs, [FirebaseDatabase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase) and [FirebaseStorage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage) are two examples, provide `getInstance()` methods that accept a `FirebaseApp` parameter.  For these, one can create a custom `FirebaseApp` using [initializeApp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#initializeApp(android.content.Context,%20com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions,%20java.lang.String)) and [FirebaseOptions.Builder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.Builder) to specify the values that are normally provided by `google-services.json`.  But [FirebaseMessaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging) does not have a `getInstance()` that accepts a `FirebaseApp`parameter, forcing use of the default `FirebaseApp` created using the `google-services.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

An application can be registered to receive messages from multiple projects. By default the project defined in the google-services.json file will be used however you can request another Instance ID token using the [getToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId#public-methods) method and manually specifying another Sender ID.

So if the user defines another sender id you can then call `getToken` and messages sent to both the initially generated token and the one you generated manually will be received by the app.